# Spinner with fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, spinner

I have a layout with spinner and a fragment below it. When I select an item in the spinner it should show related fragments. I'm new to android and I want to know how could I do that. Thanks in advance.

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"/>
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="420dp"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
```

My Java code:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

private Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spin, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(Main.this);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check which value you are getting in selection on spinner than relevant fragment you have to open.

so in

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
if(){
//Open appropriate fragment here.

}
}
```